# Detecting Date vs. Date/Time with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an input box where a user can enter a date string.

Is there any way that I can test the granularity of the date string entered by the user?

I thought that I could use `moment.get`, but that was not my answer. This is what I have:

Let's say my user enters the string "2015/10/28":

```
var input_moment = moment(input_val);   //input_val = '2015/10/28'

var hasYear     = input_moment.get('year')          > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; year = 2015
var hasMonth    = input_moment.get('month')         > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; month = 9
var hasDay      = input_moment.get('date')          > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; date = 28
var hasHour     = input_moment.get('hour')          > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; hour = 0
var hasMinute   = input_moment.get('minute')        > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; minute = 0
var hasSecond   = input_moment.get('second')        > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; second = 0
var hasMilli    = input_moment.get('millisecond')   > -1 ? 1 : 0; // 1; millisecond = 0
```

Unfortunately, all of my booleans are true. So, how can I tell what valid date/time string pieces my user entered, since the entered date/time of "2015/10/28 00:00:00" would give me the same result as above?

Is there a way to query `moment` for the format of the date/time string so that I can use that format for parsing?

Possibly:

```
input_val = '2015/10/28';

var inpt_format = moment(input_val).getFormat(); //inpt_format = 'YYYY/MM/DD'
```

I would much rather not have to parse the pieces out myself, but if that is what it comes down to, then so be it.

By the way, I am using moment version 2.4.0. I can upgrade if need be.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you test `input_val` for `":"`

Comment: `1` and `0` are not boolean values

Comment: @PaulS. I thought of that, but I was really hoping that I could have `moment` do all of the string parsing for me. I don't think that there is a valid date format out there that doesn't separate `H`, `M`, and `S` with a `:`, but who knows.

Comment: @Andreas No they are not, they are `smallint`, but honestly, who doesn't use `0` and `1` when testing non numeric values to save a few characters/bytes? In this situation it doesn't matter, and I'm flabbergasted that you would even make a point of pointing out such an obvious design choice in an example that I did not want a scroll-bar on.